# Password_hash Incorrect after updating table

Tags: php, password-hash

My login system md5 hashes the username and I password_hash the password. Therefore I cannot fetch the row based on the username? My client then enters an email address which I base64encode. I then offer a lost password change option. However, when I UPDATE the field using the same type of hash but, using the email field as an identifier, the new password is incorrect?
Below is a sample of my UPDATE, but hard coded for illustration(PS this does not work either?).

```
$em = 'example@example.com';
$em1 = base64_encode($em);
$ps = 'some password';
$password_hash = password_hash($ps,  PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$qu = "UPADTE table SET field = '$password_hash' WHERE email = '$em1'";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $qu);
```

Edited question to include my code after verifying that the user exists and sending out an email for them to positively identify themselves as the owner of the account. Here is the final processor page.

```
if(EMPTY($_POST[psw1]) ) { 
echo "New password must be supplied"; } 
elseif(EMPTY($_POST[psw2]) ) { 
echo "Repeat password must be entered"; } 
elseif($_POST[psw1] != $_POST[psw2]) { 
echo "Passwords entered do not match";
} elseif(EMPTY($_POST[eu])) { 
echo "Essential data is missing in order to complete this process.";
} 
elseif (strlen($_POST['psw1']) < 6) {
echo  "Password must be at least six characters in length";
     } 
elseif (preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['psw1']) !=      $_POST['psw1']) {
echo "Password may only contain letters and numbers";
    } 
elseif(!EMPTY($_POST[psw1]) && !EMPTY($_POST[psw2]) && !EMPTY($_POST[eu]) && $_POST[pw1] == $_POST[pw2] ) { 

include "conn.php";
echo "$_POST[eu]<br />";
$eu = $_POST[eu];
$pdw = password_hash($_POST[pw1], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$sq = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE str1 SET pf = '$pdw', cu_pw_status =    '2' WHERE cu_type = '$eu'");
echo "Your password has been changed, you may now login <a    href='login2.php'>Login</a>";
} else {
```

echo "An error occured. Contact Site Admin"; }

Comment: Hi, no the table is called str1, the column or field is called pf, this was for reference sake. The password is Updated, but is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you have column 'field' in your users table. Seems suspicios.
2. Check your update string, now it misses table name.
3. Check if you have user before updating:

   ```
   $exists = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$em1');

   if (!is_empty($exists)) {

       mysqli_query("UPDATE TABLE users SET password = '$ps' WHERE id='$exists');

       echo 'updated' . "\n";

   } else {

     echo 'no user with such email hash' . "\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, I have already checked that the user exists, sent an email to them, received a callback identifier from verified email. Then I change the password, but no go, it won't work here is the code.

Comment: Can you post actual working code? This one can't work just because you dont have quotes `EMPTY($_POST[psw1])` around object keys.

Comment: And what you mean by saying that `new password is incorrect`. If it's updated then the problem is in your login function where you verify password.

Comment: Hi, that is a bad habit of mine, but I don't have a problem with my registration or login. All works well, only the Update fails, and then the original password won't work either. I been writing this online, so now I've set up the code on Localhost and I'll try to find out what's wrong with it. I could post the entire script. Registration, login ect. Is that ALLOWED?

Comment: Thank you you were correct, if I had followed your advice earlier today I would have saved myself a lot of bother. It was my error, I was encrypting an empty value. Now and again these things do happen. Sorry